# The day before a big meeting....site disappears

Tags: server

Yup. I was finalizing a design by FTPing a revised stylesheet to my server and my entire domain went down for about 1/2 hour. It came back up but the website I wasb preparing on a subdomain shows up as a white screen. Looking at the source there is no code. However, I am able to log onto EE CP and my data is still present.

I'm currently on the line with my host (MT) so see if the issue is on their end. Has anyone experienced this on EE's end? If, so where should I start looking for a solution?

Thanks.

Update: Now I can see my raw HTML, but no CSS or EE templates.

Update: And now I just disabled the structure module and lost my site tree. :(

Comment: It sounds like there was an issue with your files on (MT). You should ask them if they can restore a more recent backup. Otherwise, this is a great opportunity for you to start to use version control. Editing live on a server is always risky, since you always have the chance of losing files. With a version control system like Git your code is safely stored so you can easily bring it back in case of disaster. There are many other benefits as well.

Comment: Thank you, Jeremy. I did request an emergency back up from last night. My question is will uploading the EE files (and database) to my domain return my site, specifically the structure module, back to the state it was before I deleted all my information? Sorry if this is a stupid question. Every day I'm reminded I'm still a newb.

Comment: It should. The Structure configuration will be in the database. The files will be your css, template (if saved as files) etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@cscott, were you saving your templates to the file system? I assume yes because you mention ftp. Check in your Exp Eng control panel under design > templates > global preferences. Is the file directory for templates that points to still valid? Are there any files there when you look using an ftp client? Next check the 'synchronize templates' and see if there is a green check mark next to all of them. If not then synchronize all of the templates. Also check if all of your template groups are there in the template manager.

I'm not sure what you mean by being able to see 'raw html but no css or ee templates'

You will likely have to reset all of the channel settings in Structure and then add each content entry back to Structure using the 'structure' tab in the Edit screen of Exp Eng for each entry. Unfortunately uninstalling the module does lose all the info.

But if you can get a backup from the hosting company just prior to the outage that would be optimal. Likely there is a mismatch currently between what is in the Exp Eng database and what is in the actual file system. Unfortunately you'll have to track down each mismatch one at a time.

Comment: Thanks, Bob. That was exactly it. I was using a literal path rather than the generic one my host recommended. They had an outage, switched the server my sites resided on and everything got messed up. I had my files restored and changed each path individually, then double checked with REElocate. Everything is back up and synchronizing properly now.

Comment: Great! It's always nice when things are back to working right. :-)